# Checking if two worksheets are the same

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to check if one worksheet is the same as another one. The example below shows how I'm doing it.

```
Dim sheet1 as Worksheet, sheet2 as Worksheet
Set sheet1 = GetObject("C:\sheet1.xls").Worksheets(1)
Set sheet2 = GetObject("C:\sheet2.xls").Worksheets(1)

If sheet1 = sheet2 Then Debug.Print("Same workbook") 'Should of course return false, but instead gives an error
```

But this gives the error `Object doesn't support this property or method`. So how does one go about comparing two sheets like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined timesheet names you can compare the name property.

```
If sheet1.Name = sheet2.Name Then Debug.Print("Same workbook")
```

Comment: Thanks, that will probably do for my purposes. But if the sheets happen to have the same name, that would fail wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, in that case it will fail. I cannot find a method in the API to compare time sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Is`...

```
If sheet1 Is sheet2 Then Debug.Print("Same workbook")
```

Details are in this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc36k535.aspx) article (except `IsNot` doesn't seem to be supported in VBA).